# How do I make/run a QEMU emulation of Windows8 through terminal

Tags: terminal, mac, macos, homebrew, virtualization

I'm trying to make a Windows8 emulator using QEMU (which I downloaded via homebrew commands). I've searched on the internet for how to do this, and am utterly confused. The one [site](https://cromwell-intl.com/open-source/openbsd-qemu-windows-howto.html) that made sense to me, the commands didn't work.

Thanks